# Binance 1 Hour Missing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, algorithmic-trading, binance, ccxt

I am doing algo trading in Binance and using ccxt in Python.
i realized today that my below code didn't work properly around 1 hour. The code "print('time', data)" produced "time 2022-05-01 19:35:00" and then same code produced "time 2022-05-01 20:45:00" next. Around 1 hour is missing.
I am using Amazon server i dont know if the problem resulted from this or not. Maybe i was banned form Binance for an hour but if this was the case wouldnt i receive any error? Could you please advise me if i broke the rate limiter?
Could you please share what could be the reasons?
Thank you.

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    "apiKey": 'xxx',
    "secret": 'yyy',
    'options': {
        'adjustForTimeDifference': True
    },
    'enableRateLimit': True
})

exchange_f = ccxt.binance({
    "apiKey": 'xxx',
    "secret": 'yyy',
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',
        'adjustForTimeDifference': True
    },
    'enableRateLimit': True
})

coin = "ETH"+"/USDT"
exchange.load_markets()
exchange_f.load_markets()
data= pd.DataFrame([[0]], columns=['timestamp'])
# some codes here

while 1:
    try:
        bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(coin, timeframe='5m', limit=10)   
        bars_f = exchange_f.fetch_ohlcv(coin, timeframe='5m', limit=2)  
        df = pd.DataFrame(bars[:], columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        df_f = pd.DataFrame(bars_f[:], columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
    except ccxt.BaseError as Error:
        print("[ERROR] ", Error)
        continue

if df['timestamp'].iloc[-2] not in data.values and (df['timestamp'].dt.minute.iloc[-2] % 10 == 5):
 data= pd.DataFrame([[df['timestamp'].iloc[-2]]], columns=['timestamp'])
print('time', data)
```

Comment: If anyone found a way to break the rate Iimiter, Amazon would swiftly nerf it. That would happen all the quicker if it were to be posted here.

Comment: sorry i couldnt understand your comment

Comment: You asked *Could you please advise me if i may break the rate limiter?* I was pointing out that any useful answer anyone might give would very rapidly cease to be useful.

Comment: Oh sorry, my question should be if i broke the limit. I am not sure if i did it and was banned or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption may be right, I used to have this problem with Freqtrade.

Binance bans you if you try to make too many requests, they remove this ban automatically just wait some time.

[Here](https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/360004492232) you can see all your limitations for Binance API.

Comment: But if it was due to the ban, wouldn't i receive a an error?

Comment: You are not always getting an error when you get a ban from Binance, it will just say that you can't make new requests right now and it will come back suddenly after a while

Comment: Thank you for your comment but i still couldnt understand how i can learn if i am banned or not. Now i am facing with same problem, api does not work. it says nothing. Is there any way to learn if i am banned or not?

Comment: Take a look at "Machine Learning Limits" in the link I shared in the answer. They say there:   ----<    More specific information than the above will not be provided. Please use trial and error to achieve your ideal trading pattern, or discuss optimal behavior with other API users. >----    which I assume means that you won't know while you are banned